# Javascript/PhP Deleting File when leaving the website

Tags: javascript, php, web, web-development-server

I am looking for a way to delete a unique file that is being generated in a specific folder. When the user leaves the page without completing the "task", the file should be deleted. The file naming is uniqe via `uniqid()`

I tried it with the following way:

```
<script>

    window.onbeforeunload = <?php unlink($_POST['localfile']) ?>;

</script>
```

But somehow this is not alway working. As example it is working when I am using the back button but when I put an other url in to my searchbar and go to the wanted destination as example google.com the file will not be deleted. How could I fix this issue or is there maybe an other way of solving this problem?

Comment: Of course that's not working. What gave you the impression it would ever work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this will ever work.  You are mixing client-side and server-side code here.

The < script > tag is javascript and will execute on the client's machine.  While the < ? php ? > tag is fired when the page is generated server-side and sent to the client.

The only reason why it would work on the back button is because the variable $_POST is set at that time.

The best way to do this is use the window.onunload event and post an ajax request

The only problem with that solution is that if the clients computer crashes it wont run the javascript, so you would implement an unreliable solution and end up with a folder full of old files that would need to be cleaned regularly.

If the file you are generating is small enough to keep in memory you should use the $_SESSION variable instead.

The javascript code is as follows

```
<script>
  document.body.onunload = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", './unlink.php, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        if (xhr.responseText) {
          //somecode
        }
        else {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  }
</script>
```

Another solution would be to use a temp table in your database that will auto delete.

If you do decide to use the $_SESSION variable just remember to call session_start(); at the beginning of your PHP script.

And you would benefit from learning the client/server relationship.

Hope this helps

Comment: Most helpful answer for a long time...I am going to use $_SESSION then...it looks a lot more useful for moy case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pleasure, glad I could help!

Comment: Let me help u out with that, people here downvote, so quick it not even funny

Comment: Just another tiny miny question^^
Am I using this correctly?
`$local = ($_SESSION['tempfile'])` Or do I need so save it as a normal file in the session? Because I am not able to reach the file after executing a form (everything on the same page)

Comment: My idea was to store the raw data you are writing to the file in the $_SESSION variable, not the filename....forget the filename, writing a file to filesystem is almost never a good idea, and should be avoided if possible.